# KurentoMediaServer: recording quality low while streaming quality is good

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, video-recording, kurento

I am using kurento-client for JS and a RecorderEndpoint connected to WebRtcEndpoint. What are the settings i can try changing? It seems like the bandwidth for the video is unnecessarily constrained, feels like 200-300 kbit/s or so - very grainy. When streaming it looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke `[setMaxVideoRecvBandwidth][1]` on the WebRTC endpoint. Like so

```
webrtc.setMaxVideoRecvBandwidth(2000);
```

You can check the bitrate that your client is sending in chrome://webrtc-internals

Comment: I need to set it on the WebRTC endpoint on server, which is receiving the video from the client and feeding it to the RecorderEndpoint right? Not on the RecorderEndpoint itself? Thanks!

Comment: @MikhailNovikov Yes, that's right, in the WebRTC in the server. Don't forget to check chrome://webrtc-internals to see what the client is sending you. It might be that the client can't send better quality than what you are already getting. Also, remember to set the recorder to store the file in webm format, that way you'l save a transcodification.

Comment: Did it. Thanks again. Can you check my another question about Kurento load limits please?